# How to get a list of updated attributes / relationships in managed object?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a notification handler. How can I get the list of updated attributes / relationships?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:[Utility class] selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:)
               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];

- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification {
    NSArray *updated = [saveNotification.userInfo valueForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
    for (NSManagedObject *obj in updated) {

        //how to get changed attributes??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` has a `changedValues` property that contains the attributes and relationships that was changed and newly assigned values are in the dictionary too. And because managed object is available also for `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` not only `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, so you get the chance to do additional modification on you managed object before saving without to use NSNotification object.